# NGRX / Angular / Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to get an application working with ngrx store/effects and angular and firebase.

I am having problems understanding why when pulling data from a service it does not work but when pulling it directly from firebase it does work.  There is only one line that i am changing in the Effects Class.

I know the service call to Firebase actually works because i call it directly in the component and display the data on the page.

However when i try to use the same service in the NGRX Effect it does not work when calling the service, i have to call into Firebase using AngularFire2.

Code Below:

**Not Working**

```
@Effect() pullArrayFromFirebase$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_CUSTOMERS_ACTION)
    .switchMap(() => {
      ***return this.customerDataService.getAllCustomers()***
        .switchMap(result =>
          Observable.of({ type: CUSTOMERS_LOADED_ACTION, payload: { customers: result } })
        )

    })
```

**Working**

```
 @Effect() pullArrayFromFirebase$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(LOAD_CUSTOMERS_ACTION)
    .switchMap(() => {
      ***return this.af.database.list('/customers')***
        .switchMap(result =>
          Observable.of({ type: CUSTOMERS_LOADED_ACTION, payload: { customers: result } })
        )

    })
```

**Service**

```
getAllCustomers(id: any = ''): FirebaseListObservable<CustomerModel[]> {


    return this.af.database.list(this.customersRef, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'parentId',
        equalTo: id
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Iam not sure if this helps with your problem, but you should better write `.ofType(...).switchMap(() => this.customerDataService.getAllCustomers()).map(result => ({ type: CUSTOMERS_LOADED_ACTION, payload: { customers: result } }));` in your effects.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own problem.  Both ways of coding the Effect work perfectly and the same.

I just has a default id = '' in my service, which was making the service return nothing, when i was calling this from my component i was passing in an ID.

Simple really - just couldn't see the forest for the trees.